# how get item from list which is in Array of Object in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, object

This is my code, I can`t get elements from the list which is situated Object array. How I can get "info" from data?

```
Object[] data = {
new List<string>() {"name", "name2", "name3", "name4",},
new List<string>() { "info", "info2", "info3", "info4",},
new List<int>() { 2002, 1999, 2005, 1980 },
new List<int>() { 12000, 1000000, 2500, 900000 },
new List<int>() { 1337, 2828, 1890, 4210 },
};
```

I tried to get elements with the help:

```
var i = data[1][1]
var i = data[1,1]
```

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a parallel array situation where the element[0] defines information about some entity or other, then [1] are attributes for another etc.  If so, better to create a class and keep related data together...and easily accessible.  Thousands of posts here show how

Comment: If you start with an `Object` array and you index it then you get an `Object`. What makes you think that you should be able to index that? Your two attempts are indexing a jagged array and a 2D array, neither of which you have.

Comment: Your first index returns object type which doesn't have indexer. You can add `using System.Collections` and cast object e.g. for IList like so `var i = ((IList) data[1])[1];` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data[1]` is not a list, it's an object, technically it is `object?`. so you cant use the index on it.

you can get the value like this.

```
var ls = data[1] as List<string>;

var item = ls[1];
```

or `var item = ((List<string>)data[1])[1];`

**Edit**:
both cases are compiling for me.

[image]

Comment: Cast to non generic `IList` is sufficient

Comment: @Qwertyluk `var i = ((IList) data[1])[1]` is giving compilation error, it should be `var i = ((IList<string>)data[1])[1];`

Comment: No, it doesn't. Remember about adding `using System.Collections;`.

Comment: Your cast can throw `InvalidCastException` since `object[]` can contain also `List<int>`.

Comment: @Qwertyluk adding the `using System.Collections` works. Thank you

Comment: is there a way to universally access an element, something like generic?

Comment: @crux. what do you mean by universally access?

Comment: tried use var i = ((IList) data[1])[1] and var ls = data[1] as List<string>; it doesn't work, i got an error   Program.cs(18, 31): [CS0021] Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: @crux. both are working for me. you can check my updated answer. I think your are missing something here

Answer (score 0):

You're treating an `Object` array as if it were a `List` array. In order to use an indexing operator on an element retrieved from the array, you'll need to denote that it's a `List`.
This is most commonly done with the `as`, `is`, `typeof`, and/or casting operators.
Here's an example using `as` and `is`:

```cs
object[] data = {
new List<string>() {"name", "name2", "name3", "name4",},
new List<string>() { "info", "info2", "info3", "info4",},
new List<int>() { 2002, 1999, 2005, 1980 },
new List<int>() { 12000, 1000000, 2500, 900000 },
new List<int>() { 1337, 2828, 1890, 4210 },
};

foreach (var item in data)
{
    if (item is List<string>)
        Console.WriteLine((item as List<string>)[0]); // Use the string however you want
}
```

For more information, I'd take a look at [Microsoft's Type-testing documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast).